# Automate the installation and configuration of Jenkins using puppet

Tags: jenkins, automation, installation, puppet, configuration-management

Is there a way to automate the installation of Jenkins using puppet language?
I want to be able to install Jenkins and its prerequisites without manual intervention, and configure it to serve requests of port 8000.
I'm using Centos 7.

Not sure where to start so any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [jenkins](https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/jenkins) ([src](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-jenkins)) puppet module on the forge that allows you to do exactly that.

Once you have your Puppet infrastructure setup, you would need to install (or add through `Puppetfile`) the `jenkins` module and classify your node with Jenkins:

```
node '<certname>' {
    include jenkins
}
```